# Iterate over Json response with Multiple JSONArray And JSONObject

Tags: json, api, parsing, jsonparser, json-arrayagg

```
{
   "Response":"success",
   "errorText":null,
   "TotalBooks":null,
   "privateBookStore":{
      "privateBooks":[
         {
            "Shopid":76354,
            "Shopname":"xyz",
            "Term":null,
            "“Strategy":[
               {
                  "Name":"ABC",
                  "ID":9
               }
            ],
            "magaerTYpe":"Single",
            "Freq":"”monthly”",
            "StructureType":{
               "Name":"ABC",
               "ID":9
            },
            "Currency":[
               "USD",
               "EURO",
               "RUPYEE"
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I have tried with JsonObject and JsonArray but the format of response is containing multiple JsonArray and JsonObject Together

I tried using HashMap and List but its not working for me. [Loop through multiple JsonObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48612897/loop-through-multiple-jsonobject) I have gone though this too.
Kindly suggest the approach

What I have so far is -

```
inputstream in = new bufferedinputstream(urlconnection.getinputstream());
String result = ioutils.tostring(in utf-8 );
JSONObject  outer = new JSONObject(result);
JSONObject  inner = outer.getJSONObject("privateBookStore");
JSONArray arr = inner.getJSONArray("privateBooks");
```

also tried with this too but not giving me key:value pair structure

```
List<HashMap<String,String>> response = new ArrayList<>();
JSONArray jsonarray = null;
    try {
        jsonarray = new JSONArray(json);
        for(int i=0;i<jsonarray.length();i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
            Iterator<?> iterator = jsonObject.keys();
            HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Object key = iterator.next();
                Object value = jsonObject.get(key.toString());
                map.put(key.toString(),value.toString());

            }
            response.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: you can convert JSON to java POJO, then from there, you can convert to map/list.

Comment: @dkb Could you please suggest the parser approach other than pojo. Since creating POJO would be costly depending on no of different types of responses I'll receive from the service.

Comment: you can have a union of all the responses and create one POJO with ignoring null type check. Also, If you know the cost of creating POJO, please let me know.

Comment: Can I use the JSON Parser or the JsonArray, JsonObject to iterate over it instead of POJO class

Comment: you can, but you need to know JSON structure before you write your parsing logic. In the end, you are doing the same as changing it to POJO.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231156/discussion-between-yougandhara-and-dkb).